# The "proper" way to test if a service is running in a script

Tags: shell-script, systemd

My problem:

I'm writing a bash script and in it I'd like to check if a given service is running.

I know how to do this manually, with `$ service [service_name] status`.

But (especially since the move to systemd) that prints a whole bunch of text that's a little messy to parse. I assumed there's a command made for scripts with simple output or a return value I can check.

But Googling around only yields a ton of "Oh, just `ps aux | grep -v grep | grep [service_name]`" results. That can't be the best practice, is it? What if another instance of that command is running, but not one started by the SysV init script?

Or should I just shut up and get my hands dirty with a little pgrep?

Answer (score 408, accepted):

`systemctl` has an [`is-active`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#is-active%20PATTERN%E2%80%A6) subcommand for this:

```
systemctl is-active --quiet service
```

will exit with status zero if `service` is active, non-zero otherwise, making it ideal for scripts:

```
systemctl is-active --quiet service && echo Service is running
```

If you omit `--quiet` it will also output the current status to its standard output.

Some units can be active even though nothing is running to provide the service: units marked as “RemainAfterExit” are considered active if they exit successfully, the idea being that they provide a service which doesn’t need a daemon (*e.g.* they configure some aspect of the system). Units involving daemons will however only be active if the daemon is still running.

Oneshot units *without* “RemainAfterExit” never enter the active unit state, so `is-active` never succeeds; to handle such units, `is-active`’s text output can be analysed instead:

```
systemctl is-active service
```

This will output “activating” for a oneshot unit that’s currently running, “inactive” for a oneshot unit that’s currently not running but was successful the last time it ran (if any), and “failed” for a oneshot unit that’s currently not running and failed the last time it ran. `is-active` always returns a non-zero status with these units, so run

```
systemctl is-active service ||:
```

if you need to ignore that.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that 'is-failed' is also an option, and is useful if you need to perform an action based on a service not started.

Comment: Note: for webmin the only working command is:
service webmin status.
systemctl won't work

Answer (score 90):

`systemctl` does have a mode suitable for scripting; use `show` rather than `status`, and add the `-p` / `--properties` and `--value` options to get only the output you want.

Here's an example (from an Ubuntu 17.04 system):

```
$ systemctl show -p SubState --value NetworkManager
running
```

Running (or otherwise) is a `SubState`. If you want to know whether a service is active, use the property `ActiveState`

```
$ systemctl show -p ActiveState --value x11-common
inactive
$ systemctl show -p SubState --value x11-common
dead
```

Notes from the `man`:

```
show [PATTERN...|JOB...]
           Show properties of one or more units, jobs, or the manager
           itself. If no argument is specified, properties of the
           manager will be shown. If a unit name is specified, properties
           of the unit are shown, and if a job ID is specified,
           properties of the job are shown. By default, empty properties
           are suppressed. Use --all to show those too. To select specific
           properties to show, use --property=. This command is intended
           to be used whenever computer-parsable output is required. Use
           status if you are looking for formatted human-readable output.

-p, --property=
           When showing unit/job/manager properties with the show command,
           limit display to properties specified in the argument. The
           argument should be a comma-separated list of property names,
           such as "MainPID". Unless specified, all known properties are
           shown. If specified more than once, all properties with the
           specified names are shown. Shell completion is implemented for
           property names.

--value
           When printing properties with show, only print the value, and
           skip the property name and "=".
```

To see available properties for a service, run (for example, for `polkit`)

```
systemctl show -a polkit
```

The possible values for `LoadState`, `ActiveState` and `SubState` are unfortunately undocumented in the manpage(s); instead they are documented in the D-Bus interface description for `org.freedesktop.systemd1`: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/org.freedesktop.systemd1.html

> `LoadState` contains a state value that reflects whether the configuration file of this unit has been loaded. The following states are currently defined: "`loaded`", "`error`", and "`masked`". "`loaded`" indicates that the configuration was successfully loaded. "`error`" indicates that the configuration failed to load. The `LoadError` field (see below) contains information about the cause of this failure. "`masked`" indicates that the unit is currently masked out (i.e. symlinked to `/dev/null` or empty). Note that the `LoadState` is fully orthogonal to the `ActiveState` (see below) as units without valid loaded configuration might be active (because configuration might have been reloaded at a time where a unit was already active).
>
> `ActiveState` contains a state value that reflects whether the unit is currently active or not. The following states are currently defined: "`active`", "`reloading`", "`inactive`", "`failed`", "`activating`", and "`deactivating`". "`active`" indicates that unit is active (obviously...). "`reloading`" indicates that the unit is active and currently reloading its configuration. "`inactive`" indicates that it is inactive and the previous run was successful or no previous run has taken place yet. "`failed`" indicates that it is inactive and the previous run was not successful (more information about the reason for this is available on the unit type specific interfaces, for example for services in the Result property, see below). "`activating`" indicates that the unit has previously been inactive but is currently in the process of entering an active state. Conversely "`deactivating`" indicates that the unit is currently in the process of deactivation.
>
> `SubState` encodes states of the same state machine that `ActiveState` covers, but knows more fine-grained states that are unit-type-specific. Where `ActiveState` only covers six high-level states, `SubState` covers possibly many more low-level unit-type-specific states that are mapped to the six high-level states. Note that multiple low-level states might map to the same high-level state, but not vice versa. Not all high-level states have low-level counterparts on all unit types. At this point the low-level states are not documented here, and are more likely to be extended later on than the common high-level states explained above.

There are many properties, so if you know what you're looking for...

```
$ systemctl show - polkit | grep Active
ActiveState=active
ActiveEnterTimestamp=Thu 2020-07-02 07:24:40 IST
ActiveEnterTimestampMonotonic=6682102
ActiveExitTimestamp=
ActiveExitTimestampMonotonic=0
```

Comment: On Raspbian I used a service which would break sometimes. Instead of "active (running)" its status would be "active (exited)". "systemctl is-active" would not differentiate. This answer gave me distinctions I needed: running / exited / dead

Comment: Great answer, thank you.  In my case I needed to care about portability (`--value` may not be available) and pattern matching, so I came up with a bash oneliner.  e.g. to list the names of services matching `apt*`

`systemctl show --type service --property Names 'apt*' | while IFS= read -r line; do [[ $line ]] || continue; printf '%s\n' "${line#*=}"; done`

Comment: It's very frustrating that the documentation which you site _does not list all the states_. For the states relevant to the "service" unit type, it refers to another documentation page, which simply does  not discuss the possible substate values or their semantics  :(

Comment: @Otheus the possible values for the *State parameters are unfortunately undocumented in the manpages; instead they are very well hidden in the description of the respective D-Bus interface: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/org.freedesktop.systemd1.html

I've taken the liberty to add them to Zanna's post.

Comment: @MartinvonWittich thank you so much for doing that! <3

Comment: FYI: in Ubuntu, "LoadState" will return a status of "not-found" when a service does not exist. I'm not sure this behavior is documented at all.

Answer (score 27):

As a complement to Zanna's answer, the `--value` option for `systemctl show` has been introduced with [version 230 of systemd](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/NEWS). So it may not be available on certain distros like debian jessie.

In this case, one can emulate the option by using sed:

```
$ systemctl show -p ActiveState sshd | sed 's/ActiveState=//g'
active
$ systemctl show -p SubState sshd | sed 's/SubState=//g'  
running
```

Answer (score 18):

I am too late to the party , however using systemctl is-active along with `&&` and `||` to this in script wont be the case all the time. The below is one I used for tomcat but can use it in method taking arguments and pass service name as arguments if u have to check multiple services but its out of scope here.

```bsh
STATUS="$(systemctl is-active tomcat.service)"
if [ "${STATUS}" = "active" ]; then
    echo "Execute your tasks ....."
else 
    echo " Service not running.... so exiting "  
    exit 1  
fi
```

This is how I made use of.... Just sharing mine.

and for the simplicity and  easy stuffs, follow others explained here :

```bsh
systemctl -q is-active tomcat.service  && \
echo "Tomcat Runnung" || \
echo "Service is not running at all "
```

Comment: How is that better than simply `if systemctl is-active --quiet tomcat.service`?  Also, `[[` isn't standard shell.

Comment: @TobySpeight You need to read my post a bit more as I mentioned in my post "This is how I made use of.... Just sharing mine."  I never said, its a standard shell usage, if u make it single bracket, it will become then but thats out of scope here. Moreover I below mention easy single line usage to do it using `&&` and `||`.

Answer (score 15):

i find this useful for command line execution or if you are making scripts.

Copied from @StephenKitt

This will check if the service is down and perform service restart

```
systemctl is-active --quiet <service name> || <service name> restart
```

the `||` there checks if the return value from systemctl is non-zero meaning if it's not active as explained by the author.

Comment: You could also use `is-failed´ to test if a restart is needed. It seems a bit more intuitive for restarting a failed service.

Comment: yes, but for me.. i wanted to practice myself and assume everything is running when it is not. so i can go things verify other stuffs with it. simply if you just want to check if it's not running, then 'is-failed' is a rightful choice. :)

Comment: I think Phil's point is that using `is-active` means that the script will restart the service even if it was stopped manually, which could cause some confusion.

Comment: I put this into a `cron` job, and added logging: `systemctl is-active --quiet <service name> || (echo '…' >> log.txt && systemctl restart <service name>)`.

Answer (score 5):

this is for init.d system

if service is not running then start service:

```
service mysql status > /dev/null ||     service mysql start &
service ssh status > /dev/null ||     service ssh start &
service php7.4-fpm status > /dev/null ||     service php7.4-fpm start &
service redis-server status > /dev/null ||     service redis-server start &
service nginx status > /dev/null ||     service nginx start  &
service cron status > /dev/null ||     service cron start &
```

when a program exits it returns also an error id, a signed byte.
on exit without problems, the value is usually 0.
on exit because of errors, the value is usually error id or frequently -1.

this value is frequently used for command integration like the numeric status id of the printed program output.

to use it with command chaining the are two options && and ||

the || checks if the exit return value is not a zero, then it runes the chained command

instead of || it impossible to write &&

the && checks if the exit return value is a zero, then it runes the chained command

similar to @asterisk answer on this page (for systemd)
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/500336/156304

Comment: IS running: `sudo service ssh status > /dev/null && echo "SSH running"`  .... or NOT running: `sudo service ssh status > /dev/null || echo "SSH not running"`

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed for my WSL2 /etc/bash.bashrc to start services.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the sed command like in the answer of Oxmel, it is enough to use `cut -d'=' -f 2` for all kind of properties queried:

for example:

```
$ systemctl show -p ActiveState sshd | cut -d'=' -f2
active
$ systemctl show -p SubState sshd | cut -d'=' -f2
running
```

Comment: That's great but you really need to give some explanation as to what those commands do.

Answer (score 3):

There are many answers using `systemctl`.

You have other options as well (where `$?` comes handy):

- Using pidof command: suppose I am trying to find if redis-server is
  running. First issue `pidof redis-server` and then check the value of
  `$?` You will find 0 if it was running; non-zero otherwise.
- Service specific solution: If the service provides a way to check if the service is running, you may use that. For the `redis-service` example, if the service is running, we will get a PONG response for `redis-cli ping` command. After issuing `redis-cli ping`, I'd check `$?` and if it's 0 then the service is running.

Comment: `systemctl` seems better in general, but in Windows Subsystem for Linux (v1), that won't work. +1 for this, which works well enough for me in WSL. If you don't want to use `$?`, you could also put, e.g., `pidof cron` in the test directly or do `cron_pid=$(pidof cron)` and use it later. The output is an empty string if the service isn't running, so one can test for it like `if [ -z $cron_pid ]; then dosomething; fi`

Comment: For those visiting from the future (As I am), or from another planetary system in the  universe. Version 0.67.6 and higher of the Microsoft Store version of WSL now supports SystemD [See this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/systemd-support-is-now-available-in-wsl/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use if/else in your bash script, as example for `service` service:

```
if (systemctl is-active --quiet service); then
        echo -e "SERVICE is Running!"
else
        echo -e "SERVICE has Stopped status!"
fi
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, it seems simple, robust, and it just works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely shameless plug since I'm the author, but I'd recommend checking out the `service::linux` task from the [Puppet Service module](https://forge.puppet.com/modules/puppetlabs/service/tasks).  It's pure Bash and comes bundled with Bolt, so you don't actually need to use Puppet at all.  e.g.

```
$ bolt task run service::linux action=status name=sshd --targets localhost

{
  "status": "MainPID=1358,LoadState=loaded,ActiveState=active",
  "enabled": "enabled"
}
```

The code uses `systemctl show`, which is [here](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-service/blob/main/tasks/linux.sh#L36-L38).  It's been in use long enough that I feel confident in recommending it, and issues and PRs are welcome to be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Also works for a non-systemd OS.

What about `ps -C service-name`? 
check `$?` for answer. If `0` it's running, if `1`, it's not running.

Example:

`ps -C privoxy && echo running`

The quiet version:

`ps -C privoxy 1>/dev/null && echo running`

**Caveat**:

I noticed that service-names longer than 14 characters can give a false positive.

Also, see comment by ''Nick S''.

Example:

Correctly shows running:

```
$ ps -C notification-daemon
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 7418 ?        00:00:04 notification-da
```

Incorrectly shows running:

```
$ ps -C notification-daemon-fake
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 7418 ?        00:00:04 notification-da
```

Correctly shows not running because less that 14 characters:

```
$ ps -C notification
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
```

I got this answer from [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-check-if-process-is-running-or-notonlinuxunix/).

Comment: Good to know about the `-C` option to `ps`. But this will false positive if another instance of the command is running, but not as a service, as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: I didn't know that. I just tested it to verify and you are correct. So, this is not a good solution.

Answer (score -2):

Have just found this great little script:

```
#!/bin/bash
service=replace_me_with_a_valid_service

if (( $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $service | wc -l) > 0 ))
then
  echo "$service is running!!!"
else
  /etc/init.d/$service start
fi
```

[Source](http://www.akamaras.com/linux/linux-script-to-check-if-a-service-is-running-and-start-it-if-its-stopped/)

Comment: Not all services have an executable of the same name, and any user could be running a command that accidentally matches - this is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: It looks like you want to make the service restarted, if it dies. In the time of `init` the keyword was `respawn` in the `/etc/inittab`. Now, with `systemd` you have to configure the service in the `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mydaemon.service`, by simply add a row with: `Restart=always`.