# script bash to check that a service is running

Tags: shell-script, shell

I have a customised linux version, kernel version is `4.1.15-klk` my platform architecture is `armv7l GNU/Linux`

I am trying to check if my process is running or not :

I tried this:

```
#!/bin/sh
service=myservice

if [ $(ps | grep -v grep | grep $service | wc -l) -gt 0 ]
then
 echo "$service is running!!!"
else
 echo "$service is not running!!!"
fi
```

but it is giving me "myservice is running!!!" whether it is running or not

I can't use pgrep since it is not available in my system

any ideas?
thanks!

Comment: When the service is __not__ running, what is the output of `ps | grep -v grep | grep $service` ?

Comment: when the service is not running I got nothing for the output of `ps | grep -v grep | grep $service` and when it is running it display the service information in one line

Comment: Unless something else comes up, I still suspect that that is where your problem is.  In your script, try `if [ $(ps | grep -v grep | grep "$service" | tee ~/service.log | wc -l) -gt 0 ]` and then inspect `~/service.log` to verify that what the output really is.

Answer (score 10):

Based on [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396630/the-proper-way-to-test-if-a-service-is-running-in-a-script), the short and scriptable way is:

```
systemctl is-active --quiet service
```

It will exit with code zero, if the service is running.

Example for printing whether the sshd service is running or not:

```
systemctl is-active --quiet sshd && echo "sshd is running" || echo "sshd is NOT running"
```

Comment: This is much, much better than any other answer here.  On any distro which uses systemd, this is THE right answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How can I use it with an `if`? I have done something like `STATUS=$(systemctl is-active service)` and then `if [ "$STATUS" = "active" ]` or `if [ "$STATUS" = "inactive" ]` ?

Comment: Answering to my question. I found it here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22726/how-to-conditionally-do-something-if-a-command-succeeded-or-failed. For example: `if systemctl is-active --quiet service; then ...` or `if ! systemctl is-active --quiet service; then ...`.

Comment: @FerranMaylinch you can also access the previous commands exit code via `$?`

Comment: This does not appear to work for `type=exec`. I just tried this on podman and the problem is the service deactivates after running.

Answer (score 3):

Use below script to check whether service running or not.
I tested for the mysql service, making it up and down and in both the conditions it's working fine.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
i=`ps -eaf | grep -i mysql |sed '/^$/d' | wc -l`
echo $i
if [[ $i > 1 ]]
then
  echo "service is running"
else
  echo "service not running"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

finally using this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20162678/linux-script-to-check-if-process-is-running-act-on-the-result), I was able to solve my problem:

```
#!/bin/sh
service=myservice

case  "$(pidof $service | wc -w)" in
0) echo "$service is not running!!!"
;;
1) echo "$service is  running!!!"
;;
*) echo "multiple instances running"
;;
esac
```

Comment: It's not working well in any case, for example it's not working properly for fail2ban.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu and CentOs systems, I'd use `ps aux` instead of `ps` alone.

Comment: `ps aux` is not supported in my system: `ps aux
ps: invalid option -- 'a'
BusyBox v1.24.1 (2017-07-21 14:28:39 CEST) multi-call binary.

Usage: ps
`

Comment: if you run `ps` is the service listed in your output?

Comment: yes the service is listed using only `ps`

Comment: Try just `ps | grep $service`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the case function to better control it.

```
#!/bin/bash
i=$(ps -eaf | grep -i mysql | sed '/^$/d' | wc -l); echo $i
case $i in
    0) echo "The mysql service is 'not running'.";;
    1) echo "The mysql Service has 'failed'. You may need to restart the service";;
    2) echo "The mysql service is 'running'. No problems detected.";;
esac
```

The first example has an error in it.
A space must be before & After '|', '||', '&' or '&&'

So it should read

```
i=$(ps -eaf | grep -i mysql | sed '/^$/d' | wc -l); echo $i
```