# grep breaks formatting of systemctl

Tags: grep, colors, systemctl

If I call command systemctl without grep, then formatting looks correctly:

[image]

Now I want to filter only lines with 'yarn', but this time line is broken into two parts:

[image]

same happens when console is two times wider. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `systemctl`’s output isn’t sent to a terminal, *e.g.* if it’s piped to `grep`, then it allows each column of its output to grow as much as necessary to fit the longest item in the list. This is what’s happening here: some unit in the list of units has a very long name, and aligning the output of all units produces the large space between `yarn.service` and `loaded failed failed`.

To filter the unit output, use `systemctl`’s built-in pattern matching:

```
sudo systemctl list-units '*yarn*'
```

You can limit the output to the lines you’d get with `grep` with the `--no-legend` option, avoid colouring and special characters with the `--plain` option, and avoid starting a pager with the `--no-pager` option:

```
sudo systemctl list-units --plain --no-legend --no-pager '*yarn*'
```

You can specify multiple patterns, the results will include any match to any of the patterns:

```
sudo systemctl list-units --plain --no-legend --no-pager '*yarn*' '*hdfs*'
```

There are better sub-commands if you want to retrieve the status of specific units; see for example [The "proper" way to test if a service is running in a script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/396630/86440).