# How to print the systemctl service Active status single only?

Tags: linux, systemctl

```
systemctl status httpd

● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2019-10-11 00:35:58 EEST; 1 weeks 3 days ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 29728 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -k graceful (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 10722 (httpd)
   Status: "Total requests: 0; Current requests/sec: 0; Current traffic:   0 B/sec"
   Memory: 8.7M
```

I want to print only below a single line along with the hostname

```
Active: active (running) since Fri 2019-10-11 00:35:58 EEST; 1 weeks 3 days ago
```

Comment: What have you tried, so far?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396630/the-proper-way-to-test-if-a-service-is-running-in-a-script

Answer (score 2):

`systemctl --no-pager status httpd | grep Active` should return the output you want.